# What does wait $! mean

Tags: bash

context of the command is

```
su postgres sh -c "$POSTGRES -D $DATADIR -c config_file=$CONF" &
wait $!
```

not recorded in the manual

```
man wait

NAME
   wait, waitpid, waitid - wait for process to change state
......
```

documentation

and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-wait
which is refered from wikipedia

Comment: And in that specific example (assuming no intervening lines between the two lines shown) it is an entirely useless use of `wait`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0024_0021):

> ($!) Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using the bg builtin

Comment: To add to this answer: Executing the command (`su ...`) in the background and immediately `wait`ing for it can be useful when using `set -e` and writing conditions whose code should still have `set -e` in place (code that occurs in conditions is usually exempt from `set -e`). I.e:
`if set_-e_disabled_for_this_function_call; then ...` vs
`if set_-e_enabled_for_this_function_call & wait $!; then ...`
In the latter case, the code after `then` will not execute if a statement in the function doesn't run successfully (like `false` -- because of `set -e`) or is `return <n>` with n != 0.

Comment: Sorry, the syntax is `set_-e_enabled_for_this & if wait $!; then ...`.
This also makes clear why it works: The function call is not inside an `if` condition, just the `wait`.

Comment: More on this topic: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside-subshells-with-parenthesis-followed-by-an-or/